# PIXIJS: Polygon contains circle?

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, pixi.js

I need to know if a given PIXI.Circle is partially inside or out of a PIXI.Polygon I drew. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Wound up doing a workaround: Built a polygon and checked all of its vertices against the other polygon